# Get query string from ActivationUri - Console Application c#

Tags: c#, console-application, query-string

I'm currently launching a console application through a url, and trying to obtain the query string from that URL. If I set the variable with the URL and query string it works fine, but when I try to call it using the URL in a browser it gives me a

> System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

here

> string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;

I've seen this work elsewhere(including a colleagues VB application) so I know i'm on the right track. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Deployment.Application;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace DRFLoader
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                 string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
                var DMNo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
                //Do stuff with DMNo here

            }
            else
            {

                string uri = "http://intra/drfloader/drfloader.application?1232222";
                var queryString = new Uri(uri).Query;
                var DMNo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
                //Do stuff with DMNo here

            }

        }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Update - The exception data is as follows:

Stacktrace: at DRF.Loader.Program.Main(String[] args)
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does this mean it's looking for a collection of some kind?

Comment: So you'r saying one of those works and one doesnt?

Comment: "ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;" - I'd start by checking which node in this is null. Is it "ActivationUri.Query" ? Is it ActivationUri already? Is it "CurrentDeployment" ...

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah sorry, I probably should've taken the else statement out, that works just fine.

Comment: @Fildor Good thinking, I just need to work out how to do that through exception handling

Comment: The stacktrace would be a good start. Please include it in the question.

Comment: I've updated the post with the exception details

Comment: I'd put each step on a separate line and step it through in the debugger. Or put debug output in between and see which lines produce output ...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, there was nothing wrong with my code. It's the curse of the single tickbox

> To enable query string passing in a ClickOnce application with
>   MageUI.exe Open the .NET Command Prompt and type:
>
> MageUI
>
> From the File menu, select Open, and open the deployment manifest for
>   your ClickOnce application, which is the file ending in the
>   .application extension.
>
> Select the Deployment Options panel in the left-hand navigation
>   window, and select the Allow URL parameters to be passed to
>   application check box.
>
> From the File menu, select Save.
>
> Alternately, you can enable query string passing in Visual Studio.
>   Select the Allow URL parameters to be passed to application check box,
>   which can be found by opening the Project Properties, selecting the
>   Publish tab, clicking the Options button, and then selecting
>   Manifests.

Basically just do the bit in the final paragraph.

[Found it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx)